# Android-Where does image taken get saved?

Tags: android, image, photo

Something weird is happening in my application im not sure if it is worth uploading all the code...

```
 Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 pictureIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo );
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I use this code to take an photo. The photo gets saved in the DCIM folder and also into imageUriSaveCameraImageto which points to sdcard/folder...The image is given the name image1.jpg..once run it works.

Then i delete the files from DCIM and sdcard/folder and run the application again and take a different photo...for some reason the old photo appears in the folder...it must be caching or storing a copy of it else where...does anyone know where and how i can delete it?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you an exact answer, but my feeling is that the MediaStore is a ContentProvider, so you may be able to call ContentResolver.delete(URI).

Answer (score 1):

Android indeed caches thumbnails of all the photos in another location.

See here:
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/30998-thumbnail-cache-can-cleared.html